# Phonegap twitter plugin for ios4

Tags: cordova, ios4, phonegap-plugins

I integrated a twitter plugin for ios using phonegp plugins as given [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/8848e8dd7f0d93810eec49fb1124f6389c963b68/iOS/Twitter). But I want the same feature in ios4 also so how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter plugin is based around the IOS5 platform that includes twitter as standard.

Twitter API uses a type of Oauth for authentication. Maybe do a search for OAuth within a webapp for a custom solution.